# Apache queries mariadb database -> how to log queries?

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, mariadb, http-basic-authentication

I got a apache2 vhost-configuration with BasicAuth. With the AuthDBDUserPWQery directive I'm checking a mariadb in the background, if the user-pw-combination exists. 
For troubleshooting I want to see the exact query, the apache sends to the db. How do I do that?

Configuration file broken down:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secret babledibu"
AuthBasicProvier dbd
AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT password from login where user=%s"
```

The last line I want to be logged with it's parameters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Enable the mariadb [general query log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/general-query-log/)